# Not able to create Hyperlink after 10599 Row in VBA excel, even right click "Link" also not working

Tags: excel, vba

code in macro

```
For Each th In driver.FindElementByClass("page-tracklist-body").FindElementsByTag("a")
   'Debug.Print th.Attribute("href")
If InStr(1, th.Attribute("href"), ".xyz", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
   Movie.Hyperlinks.Add Movie.Cells(Row, Col), th.Attribute("href")
   Col = Col + 1
End If
Next th
```

and surprise it, right click "Link" also not working. what is the problem?

Comment: There are [some limits for Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3). Maybe you reached this one: "Hyperlinks in a worksheet: 65,530"?

Comment: You Right!! when I delete one, I am able to create a new link. Thank you!!!

Comment: You can try using the `HYPERLINK()` formula instead.